# How to update a production server without overwriting user files?

Tags: php, mysql, git, file-upload, workflow

I'm new to web development, and I can't find the answer to this simple question. **I'm at my wits end here  and any help would be greatly appreciated!**

I need to regularly update files on my live website, but I feel the workflow I follow is highly inefficient:

1. I manually keep track of whether a directory/file has been modified on my localhost vis-a-vis the production server
2. For directories/files which have been modified, I replace the server files with the updated ones using FTP
3. There are user-uploaded files (e.g. photos) in some directories, and I have to be extra careful to ensure I don't overwrite these "live" directories with the test directories used on my localhost. (This feels so wrong!)

Clearly, I'm missing a best practice here - but I can't find the answer despite days of searching on the net:

1. I've considered using Git/SVN - but it doesn't seem to make sense for me since I'm a lone developer and don't have multiple people working on the same files
2. Filezilla has this useful feature which helps mark modified directories/file - but this doesn't seem to be an ideal solution

What am I missing?

PS - I'm using the PHP, MySQL, Apache stack on a shared hosting server.

Comment: NOT using source control as a lone developer doesn't make sense. It's not just for conflict resolution. Want to go back to a version of a file from 3 days ago before you attacked it with a hatchet? Easy with source control. PITA without it

Comment: like @pala_ said, it's not about a matter if you're alone as developer.. Using GIT/SVN you can keep track of your code...  so **USE** it... :)

Comment: Will it also help me avoid my file overwriting problem?

Comment: also for convenience, just store your user files in a directory outside of version control, and add that directory to the list of things to ignore for whatever source control method you use

Comment: Thanks again pala and sgt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would suggest you still go for Git / Tortoise SVN**

The best part is `feature` based branching. When each branch is a new feature, you can always experiment there without disturbing the features that are already working. Once the new feature is functional, and merged to your main branch, then you can delete the feature branch

Apart from branching and forking, there are so many features in GIT and Tortoise SVN. It shows nice comparison changes between codes (+ and green) for added, (- and red ) for removed. I found extremely handy when working on CSS in RWD

Merging also becomes easier and frictionless. Resolving conflicts is also a good knowledge to have

It can prove worthy even for lone developer. Separate branch is not only for multiple users. You can create a branch for experimenting. In a branch even if you are ahead of many steps you can always switch back to where you branched from.

**For reference**

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-preface-features.html

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/github-overlooked-features/

Comment: Thanks so much @MySQLRockstar! I'll check out tortoise :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to automate your deployment process. This is referred to as [continuous-integration](/questions/tagged/continuous-integration) in the web world. Personally I use [jenkins](/questions/tagged/jenkins), but there are many other options such as [travis-ci](/questions/tagged/travis-ci). Like in @pala_'s comment I definitely suggest using version control software, which would probably be necessary if you end up using a continuous-integration server.

If you think you want to spend the time to automate your process you need to separate your sources from the user-generated content and put these in version control. Generally I like to keep my user-generated content in a completely different directory than where my sources are, so I can replace the whole directory when the server updates the files.

If you use a service like GitHub or BitBucket to host your code, then you have the option to use webhooks that can trigger actions on your continuous-integration server when you push updated code.

[Github's documentation on webhooks](https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks/)

On the continuous-integration server you can use something like rsync to update the files in your webserver. The command would look something like this:

`rsync -avz -e ssh myproject/ user@example.com:/path/to/example.com`